# How to print array elements inversely in a given range

Tags: c#, arrays

An array A of N real numbers and two integers K and L `(1 ≤ K < L ≤ N)` are given.

Change the order of the array elements between AK and AL (including these elements) to inverse one.

```
List<decimal> data = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();
results.AddRange(data.Take(L).Reverse());
results.AddRange(data.Skip(L));
```

Comment: Hello there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you state what you have attempted yourself in your first post?

Comment: Use linq :             List<decimal> data = new List<decimal>();
            List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();
            results.AddRange(data.Take(L).Reverse());
            results.AddRange(data.Skip(L));

Comment: @jdweng: `new` is not a C keyword

Comment: @jdweng the question is tagged C, not C#

Comment: Sorry.  I believe is was originally tagged as c#.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int main(void){
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int k   = 3;
    int n   = 7;
    int i;

    for(i=k; i<=n-k; i++){
        int buff    = a[i];
        a[i]        = a[n-i+k];
        a[n-i+k]    = buff;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,  I also wrote a code the same as yours , but it didn't work....

Comment: @IlyosbekIbrokhimov does it compile ? If so, what's the output ?